# Overriding custom component property

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am making a customization of the Tabs component of ant.design. I had some difficulties with props, but I solved it by reading:
https://github.com/react-component/collapse/issues/73#issuecomment-323626120

But they are still having trouble customizing tab title

```
<ContainerTabPane {...props} tab="custom title">
```

It should be overriding the tab property. What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4102-forked-1do70?file=/index.js

Comment: The expected output would be to see `custom title` instead of `Tab 1`?

Comment: Exactly, I expected to see `custom title` on the three tabs in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It wasn't obvious, but the [4853](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4853) discussion helped me.

```
<ContainerTabs defaultActiveKey={defaultActiveKey} onChange={onChange}>
  {children.map((child) => {
    const { key, props } = child;

    return (
      <AntTabs.TabPane key={key} tab="custom title">
        {props.children}
      </AntTabs.TabPane>
    );
  })}
</ContainerTabs>
```

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4102-forked-hx1gy?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

It is not the default react behavior but it seems to be "some magic" that ant design are doing with `Tabs`. It just reads the `tab` props that each child components receive and render as a tab title. So if you replace by this would get a similar result:

```
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
<div tab="Tab 1" key="1">
  Content of Tab Pane 1
</div>
<div tab="Tab 2" key="2">
  Content of Tab Pane 2
</div>
<div tab="Tab 3" key="3">
  Content of Tab Pane 3
</div>
```

Comment: But how could my custom component modify the `tab` property internally?

Comment: good question, maybe taking a look at their code, but to solve your problem you could change the property directly on the children instead of a custom child component